# how to join new row to an existing row in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My df looks like below

```
Name    Date Class  Age Marks
A   3/17/2019   7   14  78  
B   3/18/2019   8   15  89
```

Now I have a new column of attendance and I need to add to my DF

to get output like this (I did this)

```
Name    Date Class  Age Marks   Attendance
A   3/17/2019   7   14  78      98
B   3/18/2019   8   15  89      99
```

now I get new row of attendance which I need to add below Previous attendance
Here, I need to keep on Increment the date and duplicating the class and age
of previous row and keeping NAN for Marks

```
Name    Date Class  Age Marks   Attendance
A   3/17/2019   7   14  78        98(old)
B   3/18/2019   8   15  89        99(old)
C   3/20/2019   8   15  NAN       89.7(new) 
D   3/21/2019   8   15  NAN       98.0(new)
```

note:- The place of attendance may vary, so i can't hardcode the inplace column number

Thanks in Advance

Comment: where is Cand D come from ? new data ?

Comment: Can you share the desired output?

Comment: I will get only Attendance for C and D, and I need to add the previous values for Date, class and age for C and D @Wen-Ben

Comment: @Mstaino The last table was my desired output,
where I will get only attendance and needs to add them to existing data frame with incrementing previous values

Comment: Basically it's a column wise addition of data with attendace from new datafrma and rest all from same data frame